# How to use `copy_if` filter the `str` specific multiple of index

Tags: c++, c++11

How to use `copy_if` filter the `str` specific multiple of index.

e.g. `str` is "1000020000300004000050000", I want the `newStr` is "12345".

According to **1** is **5*0**, **2** is **5*1**, **3** is **5*2**, etc.

---

The source code :

```
std::string str("1000020000300004000050000");
std::string newStr;

std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    std::back_inserter(newStr),
    [] (char c) {
        // Some specific rule I want to return.
        return ...;
    }
);
```

---

The ideal code :

```
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    std::back_inserter(newStr),
    [] (char c) {
        // I can get the index of iteration.
        return (index % 5 == 0);
    }
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple for loop?

Comment: I want to know can do the same thing in `copy_if` or not. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the string's begin and the current iterator as captures of the lambda function and use them accordingly (the lambda has to be mutable then):

```
std::string str("1000020000300004000050000");
std::string newStr;

std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
std::back_inserter(newStr),
[it = str.begin(), beg = str.begin()] (auto c) mutable {
    // I can get the index of iteration.
    return (std::distance(it++, beg) % 5 == 0);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e05afb235938eec)

Comment: This is a interesting way to do it. Just note that for non-RandomAccessIterator, `std::distance` have linear complexity (not issue for this particular case). Also generic lambda require C++14

Answer (score 0):

You can track the index in a local variable. Note that you need to capture `i` by reference. i.e. `[&i]`

```
int i = 0;
std::copy_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
    std::back_inserter(newStr),
    [&i] (char c) {
        int index = i++;
        return (index % 5 == 0);
    }
);
```